# Attaching a source of framework in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to debug some code of framework. Right now it always brings me to assembly code. Is there a way I can attach my source to framework so I can debug in framework? Any other alternatives?

Comment: You can attach framework folder with headers. You can attach headers or put classes in compile sources, but you must have source of framework not a binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug the code of a framework that your app uses, create a workspace and put the sources of the framework as well as your app source as 2 projects inside the workspace. make sure the framework is a dependency of the app, and compile and run the app.
The framework will first compile, then the app, and you can put breakpoints in the framework and do all standard debugging.

Comment: That's certainly the way, however there is some work to do to get the app to load that specific framework instance...